# Responsive Polygon SVG with hyperlink

Tags: svg, polygon, responsive

I would like to make this polygon shape with hyperlink responsive so that it shrinks to fit smaller devices. It looks fine on larger screens.

```
 <svg width="500" height="100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
   xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><axlink:href="#" target="_blank">
<polygon points="420,50 390,110 140,150 23,83" style="fill:#001;stroke:grey;stroke-width:1" />
<text fill="#dd43bf" text-anchor="middle" 
      y="90" x="210">#</text></a></svg>
```

Comment: just use a viewBox

Comment: and change the width using css ... you will also need to use the `preserveAspectRatio` svg attribute ... Sara Soueidan has a great article you can search for.

Comment: You don' really need preserveAspectRatio as it defaults to xMidYMid meet which is what you most commonly want...

Comment: Thanks for your advice